# inArray not working as expected

Tags: jquery

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Why is this not returning true? What am I missing

```
var suppliers = ["13419", "12999", "13992"];
var id = 13419;

if ($.inArray(id, suppliers) != -1) {
  console.log('duplicate');
} else {
  console.log('no dupe');
}
```

Comment: You're comparing `string` with `int`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change first element to string so the value you are searching for and values in array are same datatype

```js
var suppliers = ["13419", "12999", "13992"];
var id = 13419;

$.inArray(String(id), suppliers) != -1 ? console.log('duplicate') : console.log('no dupe');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Other option is to change every element inside your array to number

```js
var suppliers = ["13419", "12999", "13992"].map(e => {return parseInt(e)});
var id = 13419;

$.inArray(id, suppliers) != -1 ? console.log('duplicate') : console.log('no dupe');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you! How can I implement this in my real life example where I get the id from an element value? because I can't just add ' ' to the variable

Comment: Could you create fiddle as example.

Answer (score 0):

your id is integer that is

```
 var id = 13419;
```

while your arry contain strings that is

```
 var suppliers = ["13419", "12999", "13992"];
```

so give it in string like

```
 var id = "13419";
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery uses `===` to determine if items are equal. So it takes in account variable type, so You must change id type before checking:

```
if ($.inArray(id.toString(), suppliers) != -1) {
  console.log('duplicate');
} else {
  console.log('no dupe');
}
```

Or create Your own function:

```
function customInArray(needle, heystack) {
    for (item in heystack) {
            if (needle == heystack[item]) {
                return item; 
        }
    }

    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change either `supplier` or `id` datatype.

```
var suppliers = [13419, 12999, 13992];
```

Check this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y55r209t/)